# Activity scoped regular class that acts as a ViewModel

Tags: android, viewmodel, dagger-2

In the [Using Dagger in your Android app](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-dagger/#10) codelab tutorial they use an activity scoped regular class that acts as a ViewModel like so

```
@ActivityScope
class RegistrationViewModel @Inject constructor(val userManager: UserManager) {
    ...
}
```

That makes ViewModel injection by Dagger very simple but won't we loose anyting if we don't derive from the architecture components `ViewModel` class?

Comment: You're losing the ViewModel.onCleared callback.

Comment: This method is called when ViewModel is destroyed which is basically the same thing as with the activity scoped regular class. They also say that `It is useful when ViewModel observes some data and you need to clear this subscription to prevent a leak of this ViewModel.` But I just wonder: has enyone ever called it manually?

Comment: An Activity scoped regular class wouldn't be getting this callback unless you write it yourself in `onDestroy` using `if(isFinishing`, so I don't think it's the same thing :p

Answer (score 0):

In general, the code labs are related to some topic and they try to explain only this topic. Here it is Dagger, not Architecture Components. Yes, you can lose some functionality, but if they still can make their point - it does not matter.

Also if they make the app work with only plain java objects it means that they don't need the extra functionality from the ViewModel, they wrote less code so even better.

I also want to point out that the explanation that "you are losing ViewModel.onCleared" is "the smallest problem". What is the "main feature" of the VM is that you can share the same instance through the life cycle of the same Activity/Fragment or that you can share it between different Activity/Fragment.

And onCleared is something that should be used with caution because it means in some situations that you are trying to clear a reference to a thing you should not be holding in the first place.